# Problem on complex number (11th XMO Test 1 P10)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

**Problem :** Given $ t \in \mathbb{C}$. Complex numbers $x,y,z$ satisfy that $|x|=|y|=|z|=1$ and $\frac{t}{y}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{z}$. Calculate $$\left|\frac{2xy+2yz+3zx}{x+y+z}\right|$$

**My attempt :**

$$\left|\frac{2xy+2yz+3zx}{x+y+z}\right|=\left|\frac{2y(x+z)+3zx}{x+y+z}\right|$$
as $y(x+z)=txz$
$$\left|\frac{xz(2t+3)}{x+y+z}\right|$$
as $\overline{t}y=x+z$
$$\left|\frac{2t+3}{\overline{t}+1}\right|$$
now what?

Comment: Are you supposed to find a numerical value? In that case what's the point of introducing $t$?

Comment: I'm guessing one needs to evaluate the value in terms of $t$. Please clarify if that's the case.

Comment: $t$ can be any complex number with modulus in $[0,2]$, so I'm not sure how much more specific you can be beyond what you have so far.

Comment: I actually don’t know the answer , so it may be numerical or may be an expression in $t$. Source of the problem is https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h3013509p27072540

Comment: t is a parameter. You already "calculated" (resolved) that term in x,y,z into a term containing only numbers and that parameter. Hence you are done.